# Perform a search using JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, user-agent

Since the Soundcloud Java API is discontinued, I want to perform a search on their site using JSoup. I am currently using this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("https://soundcloud.com/search?q=deep%20house")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
            .timeout(5000).get();
```

But the webpage is giving me a message that I should be  using a newer browser:

```
<p class="messageText sc-text-light">Your current browser isn't compatible with SoundCloud.<br>Please download one of our supported browsers. <a href="http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/552882-the-site-won-t-load-for-me-all-i-see-is-the-soundcloud-logo-what-can-i-do-">Need help?</a></p>
```

I have tried using other user agents which I found [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/) but none seems to work so far. What can I do to prevent this message from popping up?

Comment: The page always contains the message you perceived, it just does not show up in recent browsers.

Comment: Why don't you use REST Client SDK and use their rest APIs https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists

Comment: @AllahbakshAsadullah How would I be able to perform a search using their rest APIs?

Comment: Look [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search) for how to search with api.

Comment: @JonasCz Yeah that's what I said, that is the method when using Javascript, Ruby, PHP or Python, but their Java API was discontinued.

Comment: I'm sure you can use their api with java, all you need is a JSON library.

Comment: This user agent string worked fine for me - `"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19"`

Comment: You should use https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search . First thing is you should start using Jersey Client or ApacheHttp Commmono library for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below snippet. User agent string taken from [**this**](http://www.website-watcher.info/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3595) thread.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect("https://soundcloud.com/search?q=deep%20house")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19")
                .timeout(5000).get();
System.out.println(doc);
```