# How to set language to PhantomJs Ghostdriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm using PhantomJs Ghostdriver with Java to take some screenshots of the webpages. My problem is that PhantomJs are using locale from the host machine, so I need to set default language. I have found how to do it for Chrome Driver and for Firefox, but can't find the solution for Ghostdriver.

Any hints?

Comment: Probably not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by default language? Accept-Language header? `webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Accept-Language'] = 'en-GB'` ?

Comment: yes, but how to do that in java?

Comment: `DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
cap.setCapability("phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Accept-Language", "en-GB");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);`

Comment: Looks like it ignores that, same as for resourceTimeout... :(

Comment: I dont know if it will work but you can try options given in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29789380/4720017). Try using a [userAgent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30010650/4720017) as well along with the option.

Comment: This is for specific browsers, I'm using ghost driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/228) and [**this pull request**](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/pull/229) (and tested, of course):

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX + "Accept-Language", "it-IT");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps );
```

The constant above is at [`org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_CUSTOMHEADERS_PREFIX`](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/binding/java/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriverService.java#L119).

Don't forget to change the language from `it-IT` to whatever you need.